# Ruby equivalent for Python's for / else

Tags: ruby

I've always been searching for something like Python's while / else struct in Ruby to improve my code.

That means that the loop is executed and if the condition in the loop hasn't been true any time, then it returns the value in the else statement.

In ruby, I can do like this :

```
if @items.empty?
  "Empty"
else
  @items.each do |item|
    item
  end
end
```

So is there a way to improve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, you could write it as a ternary:

```
@items.empty? ? 'Empty' : @items.each { |item| item }
```

You may want to do something more useful in your block though, since `each` is executed for its side effects and returns the original receiver.

Update as per your comment: I guess the closest you could get is something like

```
unless @items.empty?
  @items.each { |item| p item }
else
 'Empty'
end
```

Comment: I don't like it much on just a line. That's not clearer. What I want is rather something like while / else / end. Maybe it's not possible but I think the question is worth it.

Comment: I looked up Python's `while/else` now, @Zabba is right, the closest is probably an `unless..else` if you don't like the ternary form. IMHO it doesn't make sense to try to translate every construct from one language to another though, but YMMV.

Comment: I wasn't trying to translate all the language but I think this struct in Python is really useful. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 29):

Remember that the iterator block returns what you put into it, which can be tested for further use.

```
if arr.each do |item|
  item.some_action(some_arg)
end.empty?
  else_condition_here
end
```

Comment: This is hideously awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are in Ruby, let's have fun. Ruby has powerful `case` construct, which could be used such as this:

```
case items
when -:empty? then "Empty"
else items.each { |member|
    # do something with each collection member
  }
end
```

But to make the above code work, we have to modify the native class `Symbol` first. Modification of native classes is Ruby specialty. This needs to be done only once, typically in a library (gem), and it helps you ever after. In this case, the modification will be:

```
class Symbol
  def -@
    Object.new
     .define_singleton_method :=== do |o| o.send self end
  end
end
```

This code overloads the unary minus (`-`) operator of `Symbol` class in such way, that saying `-:sym` returns a new empty object monkey patched with `:===` method, that is used behind the scenes by the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

A more or less functional way:

```
empty_action = { true  => proc{ "Empty"}, 
                 false => proc{ |arr| arr.each { |item| item }} }

empty_action[@items.empty?][@items]
```