# Searching through a list of objects in Ruby and returning result(s) or raising an error if not found

Tags: python, ruby, if-statement, break

I am writing an instance method to search through a list of objects and return one or more matching results if found. I'd like it to behave like so:

```
my_foo = inst.find_obj('foo')
#=> obj_matching_foo
my_foo, my_bar = inst.find_obj('foo', 'bar')
#=> [obj_matching_foo, obj_matching_bar]
my_baz = inst.find_obj('my_baz')
#=> RuntimeError: ERROR: No obj found matching search my_baz
```

Here is my Ruby version of the `find_obj` method:

```
def find_obj(*searches)
  results = []
  searches.each do |search|
    found = false
    @obj_list.each do |obj|
      if func_returning_hash(obj.some_method)[@key] == search
        results.push(func_creating_result(obj))
        found = true
        break
      end
    end
    raise "ERROR: No obj found matching search #{search}" if not found
  end
  return results[0] if results.length == 1
  return results
end
```

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the `found` flag, as I can in Python, using `for` ... `else`:

```
def find_obj(*searches):
    results=[]
    for search in searches:
        for obj in self.obj_list:
            if func_returning_hash(obj.some_method)[self.key] == search
                results.append(func_creating_result(obj))
                break
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('ERROR: No obj found matching search %s' % search)
    if len(results) == 1:
        return results[0]
    return results
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7090452/897968), but I don't think I can use any answer from there since my loop is more complex.

Since I am new to Ruby, my Ruby code is rather "pythonic" and there might be a totally different approach I don't see yet... any answer making the Ruby code more concise while keeping its clarity is welcome!

Comment: I think the question you linked to makes it pretty clear that there is no direct Ruby equivalent of Python's `for`/`else`. So if all you're asking is "what's the direct Ruby equivalent", this question is a dup. If you're asking how to make your Ruby code more Rubiffic, that's probably a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), not SO. If you're asking something different… what in particular are you asking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby equivalent for Python's for / else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090452/ruby-equivalent-for-pythons-for-else)

Comment: @abarnert I am not looking specifically for a for/else equivalent, but for a better way in Ruby to write this method.

Comment: @abarnert changed the title to make that more clear.

Comment: As a side note, a function that raises an exception for no values, returns a single value for one, or returns a list for multiple is going to be as clumsy to use as it is to write. Why not just a function that returns a list of 0, 1, or more values in the first place? That would be more Pythonic _and_ more Ruby-like of a design, and easier to write and to use in both languages as well.

Comment: @abarnert: I know it looks rather weird on its own. I edited the use-cases at the top to explain why it should behave that way.

Comment: You realize you can unpack a single value (`foo, = inst.find_obj('foo')`), right? That has the massive advantage that it will raise an unpacking `ValueError` when the wrong number of values is found for a single argument, in the same way it already does for two arguments, instead of silently returning a list that you think is a string that blows up way down the line somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing complex things with each, then reading this documentation is the
first step.

[Documentation for Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html)

find is the obvious method that comes to mind, but there are others such as collect or map that might meet your needs as well. Two nested each loops is very un-Ruby like. The inner loop might look like this

```
matches = @obj_list.find { |obj| func_returning_hash(obj.some_method)[@key] == search }

raise "ERROR: No obj found matching search #{search}" if matches.nil?
results << matches.map { |obj| func_creating_result(obj) }
```

That's still fairly ugly and not very Ruby-like.

There are lots of ruby style checkers out there these days. Sandi-meter, reek, etc. Using these tools will help you a lot with grokking the ruby way. Coming from python they will seem quite picky and silly, but if you want to get the Ruby way they are very useful.

As an aside, this code screams for a refactoring. You are breaking almost all the basic rules for designing reusable objects. But that can wait...

[Sandi Metz Rules for Object Design](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers)

Comment: Beautiful, that's the sort of thing I was looking for. Unfortunately, I can't use the core `find` part of it, since I found that the `@obj_list` doesn't conform to the Enumerable API. Accepted your answer anyway. Thanks!

Comment: If you've got src to @obj_list and it already implements each, all you need to make it Enumerable is `include Enumerable`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220634/how-do-i-use-the-enumerable-mixin-in-my-class

Comment: +1 for the hint, unfortunately `@obj_list` is a Ruby binding of a C++ object of the application I am scripting.

Comment: You can always reopen a class and add code. `class ObjList ; include Enumerable ; end `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more functional approach

```
def find_obj(*searches)
  results = searches.map do |search|
    search_res = @obj_list.map {|obj|
      if func_returning_hash(obj.some_method)[@key] == search
        func_creating_result(obj)
      end
    }.compact

    raise "ERROR: No obj found matching search #{search}" unless search_res.any?
    search_res
  end.flatten(1)

  results.length == 1 ? results.first : results
end
```