# Rails: How to check the number of each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to know the number of `each do` in view.

For example,

```
  <% schedule.rooms.each do |r| %>
    <% r.events.each do |e| %>
```

If there is no `r.events`, I'd like to add something.

```
  <% schedule.rooms.each do |r| %>
    <% r.events.each do |e| %>
      <% if _r.events is not exist_ %>
        do something
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Comment: you can also do what's recommended in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090452/ruby-equivalent-for-pythons-for-else, the second answer which has 20 points looks nice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @fanta. It works! I didn't know I can add `if` clause with `each do`.

Comment: @fanta that's not very idiomatic. My answer is more idiomatic Ruby, and clearer in terms of code and intention.

Comment: @Mohamad Indeed, but it looks cool.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the current `room` instance in the loop has any events associated with it, using `any?`.

```
<% schedule.rooms.each do |room| %>
  <% if room.events.any? %>
    there are events, loop over them...
    <% room.events.each |event| %>
       do something with `event` instance 
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    no events, do something else
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also invert the logic and use [`none?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/none%3F) or `empty?`

```
<% if room.events.none? %>

<% if room.events.empty? %>
```

Or use `unless`.

```
<% unless room.events.any? %>
```